# Loop through a string and prefix each character with a different value

Tags: java, bukkit, bungeecord

I'm developing a command for my Minecraft server using Bungeecord and need a way to add a different colour code to the beginning of each character in a string. The hope being that I can turn any string they enter into being printed with a rainbow colour. I've been requested to use 8 different colour codes, and repeat the sequence for each 8 characters that pass.

I've registered the command and everything like that and it works, it's the string manipulation that I'm having trouble with. I know that to loop through a string I can use

```
String message;
for (int i = 0; i < message.toCharArray().size(); i++)
{
  char c = message.charAt(i);
  //Prefix code here
}
```

I've also defined the 8 colours I want to use

```
final String one = "4";
final String two = "6";
final String three = "e";
final String four = "a";
final String five = "b";
final String six = "9";
final String seven = "5";
final String eight = "d";
```

What I need is something that will accept a string such as

This text is now rainbow!

and will loop through every char and place "§one" - "§eight" in-front to colour each letter.

I've tried using String#replace(string, string) however this doesn't accept a char. I also tried using something along the lines of

```
String.replace("" + c, "§" + one + c);
```

However this didn't work either. Any help and/or pointers you could provide would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you

EDIT: Sample line of desired output

user does /rainbow This text is rainbow!

Output: §4T§6h§ei§as §bt§9e§5x§dt ...etc, but restart from §4

Comment: Sounds like a job for `StringBuilder`. You could always loop through each char, add the prefix + the char to a `StringBuilder`, then use the builder for the finished result, or you can insert things using the `insert` method

Comment: Also, don't use `toCharArray()`. Just use `message.length()` to prevent creating an excess object each time. Strings are immutable, so any attempt at modifying one creates a new String object. Since a `char[]` would allow you to modify the `String`, `toCharArray()` returns a *new* `char[]` object, not the actual `char[]` for that `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be easier if you store your colors in an array. Store the amount of colors in a variable so you don't keep doing `colors.length` in your loop.

```
String [] colors = {"4", "6", "e", "a", "b", "9", "5", "d"};
int numColors = colors.length;
```

Create a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

Loop through the array of characters. Append the correct color to the character. `i%numColors` will allow the color array to go back to the beginning if your message string is greater than 8 characters since your array currently has 8 options.

```
for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
    builder.append("§");
    builder.append(colors[i%numColors]);
    builder.append(message.charAt(i));
}
```

Then at the end of your method, just return the entire builder string.

```
return builder.toString();
```

If you want a space or a new line in between each character, just do builder.append `""` or `/n`.

Comment: Awesome idea with the array, I'll definitely be implementing that! When I tried the rest of the code however, it's appending the same string infront of the coloured version inside of squared brackets, any idea why?

Comment: @Jaydin Are you referring to `§`? I though you wanted that in front of everything? What output are you getting now?

Comment: @Jaydin Can you post a sample line of output how you want it to look?

Comment: This is what I get http://imgur.com/EePVsiC
also edited post to include desired output

Comment: @Jaydin You need to change `message.toCharArray().size()` to `message.toCharArray().length`. I updated my code.

Comment: @Jaydin Or better yet, just do `message.length()` and skip the whole `toCharArray()`

Comment: Same thing is still happening. Not sure why there's a second string being prefixed onto the finished string. Here's the method as it is

http://pastebin.com/p9vchUnh

Comment: @Jaydin You should not be passing in message to the StringBuilder constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this would be to loop through each char, then add it to a `StringBuilder` along with the prefix:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
    char currentLetter = message.charAt(i);

    if(currentLetter == ' ') //skip spaces; optional
        continue; 

    String prefix = ...; //grab a prefix
    builder.append(prefix + currentLetter);
}

String coloredMessage = builder.toString();
```